# Dice Roll Game Alternative Check

Tags: recreational-mathematics, game-theory

I have a dice roll game and I am trying to find a mathematical way to solve it.

The rules of the game go like this:

---

Directions for Play:

Each player takes a turn rolling the dice and looking for runs.  The runs can start with any number (1-2-3, 3-4-5 and so on).  Each part of the run scores five points.  A players can have more than one run in a roll.  In order to earn the score the player must correctly calculate the maximum score of the roll - if they do not they do not score any points.  The first to reach the inputted "score to play to" wins the game.

Examples of Play:

Roll 1:   1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2

The following runs can be scored; 1,2,3,4 (20 points) + 1, 2 (10 points)  The roll is worth 30 points.

Roll 2:   1, 4, 6, 6, 3, 3

The following runs can be scored; 3, 4 (10 points)  The roll is worth 10 points

Roll 3:   4, 6, 1, 2, 3,

The following run could be scored; 1, 2, 3, 4 (20 points) The roll would be worth 20 points,

The following runs could also be scored; 1, 2, 3 (15 points) + 3, 4 (10 points)  The roll is now worth 25 points.

---

The information I will know is how many of each number was rolled. Is there any way I can just use this info in a mathematical formula to solve it?  and if so what is the formula? Thanks to anyone who takes the time to help :)

Comment: Please define what a "run" is. Your examples challenge my intuition.

Comment: A run is two or more consecutive numbers at any point. For example these are all runs: 1,2  | 2,3 | 5,6 | 3,4,5 | 2,3,4,5,6| These are not runs: 1  |2,4,6|4,6|

Comment: In your Roll 3, you use the (single) 3 for two different runs.  If this is allowed, then you would have the runs 1,2 (10 points), 2,3 (10 points), (3,4) 10 points for 30 points, more than your 25.  Could you clarify the rules? Cheers!